# Microsoft Edge refuses to load the XAMPP sample site

Tags: xampp

I downloaded and set up XAMPP 7.0.1, and configured it to run on port 8080 via the config file.

If I now go into Chrome, and visit localhost:8080, it loads as expected:
[image: Working in Chrome]

Doing the same in Edge however causes the page to flash, and bring up a dialog asking me what program I want to open the file with:
[image: Not working in Edge]

I know Edge can view pages on local servers since I use Webstorm's server all the time.

Does anyone know of a way around this, since I prefer to test in Edge.

Comment: Have you typed out explicitly with the `http://` starting?

Comment: @ceejayoz Wow, I feel retarded. It didn't need that when using Webstorm -_-. Yes, that solved it. Answer, and I'll select it.

Comment: Not retarded. I only know this can happen because I too have spent time banging my head into brick walls over it. :-p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I've found that IE occasionally will treat a TLD-less domain like `localhost` as a non-HTTP request like this. Typing explicitly `http://localhost:8080` is annoying but will generally make it work.